# application.IsTrusted returns false

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

The following code (found on internet) doesn't work as `OutApp.IsTrusted` returns false.

When I try to run the code I have a bug with the following line `Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor" --> Application-defined or object-defined error

I use the code in excel vba as I don't have vba macro available in Outlook. 
My outlook version is 2013.

```
Sub emailFromDoc()
Dim wd As Object, editor As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim oMail As MailItem
Dim OutApp As Object

Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set doc = wd.Documents.Open("\\Chdcvnas0351.ch.hibm.hsbc\user.hbeu$\43987788\Documents\Market Update.docx")
doc.content.Copy
doc.Close

Set wd = Nothing
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set oMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With oMail
    .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
    Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
    editor.content.Paste
    .Display
End With
```

End Sub

If someone can help me, it would be much appreciated.
Best regards
Yoan

Comment: What exactly is your question? For an out of process caller, like Excel, it will always return False. There is no way to change that.

Comment: Yes sorry I amended my post. I have a bug with the Set editor=.GetInspector.WordEditor --> Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 2):

Of course - you are accessing `Outlook.Application` object from outside of the outlook.exe address space, hence your instance of the `Outlook.Application` object is not trusted and will raise security prompts when you access sensitive information. Only COM addins and Outlook VBA get a trusted version of that object.

As for the `GetInspector.WordEditor` error, try to access that object after calling `Display`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dmitry, But how can I copy the word's content in the email body ?

Comment: What you have above should be fine. Just try to call Display *before* accessing the WordEditor property.